# Django "surrogates not allowed" error on model.save() call when text includes emoji character

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unicode, emoji

We are currently in the process of building a system that stores text in a PostgreSQL DB via Django. The data gets then extracted via PGSync to ElasticSearch.

At the moment we have encountered the following issue in a testcase

**Error Message:**

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 159-160: surrogates not allowed`

We identified the character that causes that issue. It is an emoji.

The text itself is a mixture of Greek Characters, "English Characters" and as it seems emojis. The greek is not shown as greek, but instead in the `\u` form.

Relevant Text that causes the issue:

```
\u03bc\u03b5 Some English Text \ud83d\ude9b\n#SomeHashTag
```

`\ud83d\ude9b\` translates to this emoji:

As it says here: https://python-list.python.narkive.com/aKjK4Jje/encoding-of-surrogate-code-points-to-utf-8

```
The definition of UTF-8 prohibits encoding character numbers
between U+D800 and U+DFFF, which are reserved for use with the
UTF-16 encoding form (as surrogate pairs) and do not directly
represent characters.
```

PostgreSQL has the following encodings:

- Default:UTF8
- Collate:en_US.utf8
- Ctype:en_US.utf8

Is this an utf8 issue? or specific to emoji? Is this a django or postgresql issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reproduce the issue:

```
x='\u03bc\u03b5 Some English Text \ud83d\ude9b\n#SomeHashTag'
print(x)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>  UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in
> position 21-22: surrogates not allowed

**Solution**: apply `raw_unicode_escape` and `unicode_escape` codecs (see [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)) as follows:

```
y = x.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-16_BE','surrogatepass').decode('utf-16_BE')
print(y)
```

> ```
> με Some English Text 
> #SomeHashTag
> ```

Comment: `x == x.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape')`, so is unnecessary.  `y = x.encode('utf16',errors='surrogatepass').decode('utf16')` works